# jQuery mobile : ui-helper-hidden-accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

In my html code:

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="containdiv" class="no-field-separator">
    <label for="field1" class="ui-hidden-accessible">To</label>
    <input type="search" name="field1" id="field1" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Field #1?" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="field1val" name="field1val"/>
</div>
```

In the DOM, after being processed by jQUery mobile, has inserted the follwing element

```html
<span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
```

In between my search `input` and my hidden `input`.

As the user types in my search input, I do some stuff, and update the value of the hidden field with it.

As this happens, I notice that this span (with class "`ui-helper-hidden-accessible`") has its content updated with the value of the hidden input.

I am not sure what is happening, or what this is triggered by.

Investigating, I have found that:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ui-helper-hidden-accessible-change

The purpose of this field is actually for it to be "hidden but still accessible", however, this does not appear to be the case - it renders as visible within the browser.

Is there a way to disable jQuery from creating this element within my form?

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in jsFiddle? Your fragment of markup with just JQM renders as expected (input hidden is hidden) and no such span in DOM.

Comment: This might help: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hide the class on focus:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
focus: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").hide();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try this.

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can disable what jQuery Mobile is doing, but if I'm understanding your needs, have you tried something like just hiding the element?

```
$(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").hide();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").remove();
```