# Auto-completion using JQuery UI in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using Tag-it and JQuery UI to support tag completion in the ASP.NET application. When I entered something in the textbox, I got the messages written inside the span with the class .ui-helper-hidden-accessible. I've used display:none to hide it from the user, but the span is still filled with divs whenever I enter something in the textbox. Is it possible to disable that or should I somehow clean that span? Is it a normal behaviour?

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I've looked into [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300161/jquery-mobile-ui-helper-hidden-accessible) but it doesn't allow the user to enter a tag by pressing the enter button and neither does it prevent span from growing.

Comment: This keeps the text box filled with data, and may be what you're looking for: https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete

Comment: Thanks, I'm probably gonna look it up later since I don't want to change the application right now,

Comment: It's not changing, it's modification If you change the autocomplete source file, it will run perfectly fine.